# Xcode validation failure

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, provisioning-profile

Validation of an archive for uploading to the store is failing in the Xcode Organizer with this message: "Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets: Xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets and failed to do so because of the following issues. Permissions failure - Your account does not have permission to create profiles."

This problem has been reported by several other people on StackOverflow and Apple Development Forums, with no resolution. Here I'll explain some things I've tried with the hopes that maybe someone can suggest a solution. This is a really important problem because it's preventing release of an app.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Does anyone know what the "permission to create profiles" is referring to? From my understanding, the Organizer should just be signing the app with an existing Provisioning Profile, not creating any new ones.

Background information: I have admin privileges in a company team and am able to build the project fine. My development certificate works ok for installing to a phone. There are no expired certificates in my Keychain and the certificates in the key chain look ok. I have rebuilt the Distribution certificate and downloaded it to my Mac successfully.

The problem occurs whether I select manual or automatic provisioning in Project Settings (though this shouldn’t affect archive validation anyway). I have the original distribution Certificate on my machine from importing a .p12 file from the original developers. I’ve tried rebooting my Mac, restarting Xcode.

Issues I can think of looking at next: (1) I am using a wildcard in the app bundle name in the Distribution Provisioning Profile. Is there any problem with this? The wildcard seems to match the app bundle ID in the build. The app has previously been released without an explicit app bundle name in the provisioning profile. (2) The distribution provisioning profile has no services enabled. The app Project Settings include one service: Remote Services under Background Modes. Is there a problem because of this mismatch? (3) Should I try using Application Loader instead of the Xcode Organizer?

Comment: App Store Distribution profiles cannot have wildcard bundle IDs.  It shouldn't even let you do that on the developer site.  It's not an In House Distribution profile, is it? Because wildcards are allowed for those, but you can't submit to the app store with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, it turns out, was a bad Distribution Certificate. The team I was working for turned out to have two Apple Developer accounts with the same name, but one was an Enterprise account and the other was not. I had been given the Distribution Cert for the Enterprise account. Once I deleted all my relevant certificates from my keychain and XCode Preferences/Accounts and read in the .p12 file for the correct Distribution Cert, everything worked.

Comment: so distribution profiles with wildcards do work? if so @wottle should delete his comment to prevent further misunderstandings.